# Split Date and time in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am getting date as below

```
2010-10-18,09:11:00
```

How to split date and time in comma seperated values like `2010,10,18,09,11,00`

I tried `Date.split('-').join(",")` but i get as `2010,10,18 09:11:00`

I also want to split time into comma seperated value. So my final output is `2010,10,18,09,11,00

How to achieve this using javascript or jquery? Also i may get date time in either of following format

```
2010-10-18 09:11:00 or 2010.10.18 09:11:00
```

**Update**`

Sorry i get date as below `2010-10-18 09:11:00`

Comment: I answered your question, you should prolly check out a [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), IMO there pretty easy to master and a powerful tool for any programmer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Super easy to do with regex:
`var str = "2010-10-18,09:11:00"

var replaced = str.replace(/[-,:\s]/g, ",")`

Comment: if there space between date and time then this regex will fail. isnt it? or am i wrong? please see my update